# Dart/Flutter: How to best process hardware events in an infinite loop

Tags: flutter, dart-async, dart-isolates

I have an infinite loop that runs in a an async function in a Flutter application (although the code is pure Dart, no Flutter API is used on it).

Basically, it processes some math stuff, but I want to be able to update the data to be processed with an event coming from hardware (in this specific case from the microphone).

In order to give the fast `while(true)` the opportunity to get events from the outside, I added a delay with a duration of zero.

```
doStuff() async {
  while (!stopFlag) {
    processMathStuff(dataModifiedByHardwareCallback);

    // Without this, the loop can't be interrupted.
    await Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
  }
}
```

And although that seems to work in most platforms, calling `Future.delayed` like that makes this loop much slower than I would like. The question is if is it there a better (faster) way of doing this. This even looks kind of a hack to me. I tried calling `Future.delayed` only every a certain amount of iterations, but doing so even as often as every 10 iterations, the system loses events.

By the way, `processMathStuff` does not contain loops internally, so it is really O(1).

**NOTE:** If I move the code to an Isolate, I get a similar problem with the Isolate not listening to the sendPort stuff if the `while(true)` lacks that kind of "yield".

Comment: It's a wild stab but could you turn stopFlag into a Stream<bool>.

Comment: Thanks. I did not explain well my self: what needs to be received is not that flag, but info processed by what is represented by "processMathStuff()". The original source of that info comes from hardware associated callbacks. I can use streams in the middle, but even injecting the callback straight from processMathStuff does not work without the await Future.delayed call.

Comment: @ChrisReynolds, Thanks for your comment. I modified the question to make this point clearer. In fact in one of the implementations that I tried, the data to be processed is coming from a stream.

Comment: I don't know the efficiency of streams and you didn't say why you didn't like the implementation, but one possibility is that your hardware callback places items on one stream and your stopflag can also place a message on the same stream. Then your while loop is just processing the stream.

Comment: Thanks. I will try a pure stream implementation and see how it goes.